# How to get position of the bottom left corner in an matplotlib axes?

Tags: matplotlib, position, alignment, axes

I would like to have the bottom left corner of my plotting area, to add an red dot there (after it is saved to a ".png" and loaded somewhere else.)
Here is the plot:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 300   
x= np.arange(0,10,1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(1,1))
plt.plot(x,x)
```

[image]

Now I save the plot and reload it, further I want to see some properties of positions:

```py
fig.savefig( "bla.png",bbox_inches='tight' )
image1=plt.imread("bla.png")
print("(y, x, color) = " , image1.shape)
print("Position =" , ax.get_position())
```

Output:

```
(y, x, color) =  (357, 348, 4)
Position = Bbox(x0=0.125, y0=0.125, x1=0.9, y1=0.88)
```

ok, now I try to add a red dot at the position, where my plotting area is starting:

```py
red = [255,0,0,1]
blue= [0, 0 ,255,1]
image2= image1.copy()

(y,x) = (0,0)
image2[y:y+3,x:x+3] = blue

(y,x) = (357,348)
image2[y-3:y,x-3:x] = blue

yp = int(0.125*357)
xp = int(0.125*348)

(y,x) = (yp,xp)
image2[y-3:y+3,x-3:x+3] = red

plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(image2)
```

This is not what was expected.

[image]

Do you have any idea how I can get this left bottom corner?

Comment: You really need to add your dots before saving the plot. Once saved including axes and ticks, it's much too cumbersome to find corresponding coordinates. You would be better off adding the dots manually, for example with an image editor such as gimp.

Comment: If you really, really need to add points to such images, you could save them without any axes and borders, save the axis limits as text somewhere else and recreate stuff. Depending on the needs, things quickly get too complicated for what they are worth.